# "The signature or decryption was invalid" when trying to access web service over WSE or WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, wse

I've been given a WSDL and the URL of a webservice that I need to hit using C#.  The webservice is accessed over HTTPS, and I was instructed that I need to sign the SOAP payload with a certificate that has been provided to us.  We were also provided with a sample SOAP message, and when I plug that into soapUI it returns a valid response.  That message looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xis="http://paymetric/2007-07/XiSecureWS.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="CertId-94D3D696D2D0F9176413124110633037" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature Id="Signature-3" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-2">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>0YnXlBdLNSbCMUP0Tuiu3c2ye+g=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
LBpI+U/3Q9utuaNR/8j4smX1VGoOCeexbDmL6xM4nrHpHyNys1J6kOJIwGLOW0XEKRzTbdil5JjO
iKR/jzg5hw==
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-94D3D696D2D0F9176413124110633038">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STRId-94D3D696D2D0F9176413124110633039" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#CertId-94D3D696D2D0F9176413124110633037" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <xis:sEncrypt_Input>
         <xis:MaxUnmaskedDigits>4</xis:MaxUnmaskedDigits>
         <xis:isUnmaskedFromLeft>1</xis:isUnmaskedFromLeft>
         <xis:strRawValue>1234123412341234</xis:strRawValue>
      </xis:sEncrypt_Input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've tried to access this service using WSE 3.0 and WCF.  I know that WSE is obsolete and that I shouldn't be using it, but I'm getting desperate for something that works at this point and I'm not having any better luck with WCF.

Here's my WSE implementation:

```
XiSecureWSService svcXi = new XiSecureWSService();
            SoapContext context = svcXi.RequestSoapContext;

            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName,
                "certificatelookupinfo", false);

            X509Certificate2 cert;
            X509SecurityToken signatureToken;
            if (certs.Count == 1)
            {
                cert = certs[0];
                signatureToken = new X509SecurityToken(cert);
            }
            else
            {
                signatureToken = null;
            }

            MessageSignature sig = new MessageSignature(signatureToken);

            context.Security.Tokens.Add(signatureToken);
            context.Security.Elements.Add(sig);
            context.Security.MustUnderstand = false;
            context.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60;

            sEncrypt_InputType xiInput = new sEncrypt_InputType();
            xiInput.MaxUnmaskedDigits = 4;
            xiInput.isUnmaskedFromLeft = false;
            xiInput.strRawValue = "1234123412341234";

            sEncrypt_OutputType xiOutput = svcXi.pm_SingleEncrypt(xiInput);
```

and here's my WCF implementation:

```
XiSecureWSPortTypeClient client = new XiSecureWSPortTypeClient("XiSecureWSServicePort",
                                                                           "https://endpointaddress");

            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName,
                                                                       "certificatelookupinfo",
                                                                       false);

            X509Certificate2 cert;
            X509SecurityToken signatureToken;
            if (certs.Count == 1)
            {
                cert = certs[0];
                signatureToken = new X509SecurityToken(cert);
            }
            else
            {
                cert = null;
                signatureToken = null;
            }

            SecurityHeaderType security = new SecurityHeaderType();
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

            sEncrypt_InputType xiInput = new sEncrypt_InputType();
            xiInput.MaxUnmaskedDigits = 4;
            xiInput.isUnmaskedFromLeft = false;
            xiInput.strRawValue = "1234123412341234";

            sEncrypt_OutputType xiOutput = client.pm_SingleEncrypt(security, xiInput);
```

and my .config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="https" binding="customBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="MyCustomBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" includeTimestamp="true" />
          <httpsTransport keepAliveEnabled="false" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://endpointaddress" binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="MyCustomBinding" contract="XiSecureWSPortType"
        name="XiSecureWSServicePort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The SOAP calls that are generated through WSE look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action wsu:Id="Id-c93385e7-4e68-4e65-b73f-e0d6040b407a">http://endpoint.wsdl/pm_SingleEncrypt</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID wsu:Id="Id-dbdda6fd-6d3f-4b1d-8b30-34b87567d865">urn:uuid:054e3fdd-c1ab-4ef8-9e45-d6edbf462272</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:ReplyTo wsu:Id="Id-5704430b-7323-468d-9073-ce6f4adb03c6">
            <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:To wsu:Id="Id-795dab74-1cab-44ed-8c1e-6cf5db6d89c5">https://endpointaddress</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-5c742cc5-9653-45f3-81cf-691d5e76861c">
                <wsu:Created>2013-03-08T19:53:18Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2013-03-08T19:54:18Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-d1c1eee1-4eaa-4418-8d80-4416b05b4745">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                    <Reference URI="#Id-c93385e7-4e68-4e65-b73f-e0d6040b407a">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>kOQUVB/DeBZJiM5sOBtjdtuxXlg=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-dbdda6fd-6d3f-4b1d-8b30-34b87567d865">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>pJRl5c7txgnw4rXEWzrFrmOBVPE=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-5704430b-7323-468d-9073-ce6f4adb03c6">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>YBG6XGu50bEz+yGcUl6LSflpegM=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-795dab74-1cab-44ed-8c1e-6cf5db6d89c5">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>LOUX6dBXgV0UI+2Xz2SbvXCjLZg=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Timestamp-5c742cc5-9653-45f3-81cf-691d5e76861c">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>tUlKm/sCne9jjjlg/oOtycdFUhI=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Id-44ed0eaf-f408-45ac-b703-fff9b3fdd638">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>ekZF3fuslJcNRjuXNekGZ49Hdq8=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>K1MfLOS6sHmPxVsaLgTHoS9/Kisy/T07Um0/qlpV+246F+jPy1HbU+K0/pnAGESgLnzzA8bbGp7fZxmoIOx6oAONtI7sqM6E6OxY9g0aw+b+XAL65JT+9cXIKLNOUs9O9f301PGmlJ0ldocz0TkAX9NQTxdv8e8zqhsBLsH9kKo=</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-d1c1eee1-4eaa-4418-8d80-4416b05b4745" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body wsu:Id="Id-44ed0eaf-f408-45ac-b703-fff9b3fdd638">
        <sEncrypt_Input xmlns="http://endpoint/xsdname.xsd">
            <MaxUnmaskedDigits>4</MaxUnmaskedDigits>
            <isUnmaskedFromLeft>false</isUnmaskedFromLeft>
            <strRawValue>1234123412341234</strRawValue>
        </sEncrypt_Input>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The WCF SOAP request looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <h:Security xmlns:h="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo8nVLrfiqatEmo8IboHWGp0AAAAA1E1NtzXJZEGIoAvEM9FGvDB0fAYl39xBpJzQdMwSA8IACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
        <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2013-03-08T21:13:18.546Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2013-03-08T21:18:18.546Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-ecc8d8b8-ede9-46f6-b589-5d3b606a051a-1" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">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</o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                    <Reference URI="#_0">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>8Jq254k3Mqm2AZ58M/7SZ0Oj9hY=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>oUQgQmYxq+RvetZYGBzHMg953V+w0hxoT5BAICFs1xDuNoJi2SYIO2nvyHrywVGpvqMLeY+K89FI9SdfMyPJx6iReZm/QB8gTP5ZwkY9YQxyEEn6hlVnU+CUYaQmBtnAXMJJkQxS+OAzz3SfGBcXZSulGMwRS1fJtbC3tNtBfF4=</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference URI="#uuid-ecc8d8b8-ede9-46f6-b589-5d3b606a051a-1" />
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <sEncrypt_Input xmlns="http://vendor/xsdfile.xsd">
            <MaxUnmaskedDigits>4</MaxUnmaskedDigits>
            <isUnmaskedFromLeft>false</isUnmaskedFromLeft>
            <strRawValue>4100123412341234</strRawValue>
        </sEncrypt_Input>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

No matter what I try using WSE, I get an error that says that "the signature or decryption was invalid."  If I try the WCF implementation, I get that "the data in element 'o:Security' must be understood but cannot be handled."  I've been pulling my hair out over this - does anybody have any ideas?

edit: Current SOAP request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <h:Security xmlns:h="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" u:Id="_2" />
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo9KISySaFjJMiAw5zk9o3qYAAAAAxhoAIROo00iQikvZBzGIH8wpfBfX1e1Kg29TMjN6keYACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
        <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
            <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-bf6b0577-5466-4726-ac5e-2ba07665475f-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">MIICrDCCAhWgAwIBAgIFLtjzLRAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgZQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIEwJUWDEQMA4GA1UEBxMHSG91c3RvbjEYMBYGA1UEChMPUGF5bWV0cmljLCBJbmMuMQ0wCwYDVQQLEwRTYWFTMRswGQYDVQQDExJQTUNBLnBheW1ldHJpYy5jb20xIDAeBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEW1pc0BwYXltZXRyaWMuY29tMB4XDTEyMDgzMTE1NTYyOFoXDTE0MDgyMTE1NTYyOFowgY0xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIDAJTQzETMBEGA1UEBwwKQ2hhcmxlc3RvbjESMBAGA1UECgwJQmxhY2tiYXVkMQwwCgYDVQQLDANVQVQxFjAUBgNVBAMMDUxpbmRhIENvbGxpbnMxIjAgBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWE25vb25lQGJsYWNrYmF1ZC5jb20wgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAKvvNxFm5pXQepTeBkonadC9AHAlZrwyJheNewJ7gaS+jGNAFPHOabiUHS99TIo5Qp9+iwkKBeHuCiiJCeBzhBUVjTJ+CQFbJc12IhVRvOeW5xnyawbe+025BkK+xfjDFvTU2LIZjAV+3y+TADVWUV4VSALlwARKHH2EOu0JaZqfAgMBAAGjDzANMAsGA1UdDwQEAwID+DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQCGQfBXqMe/Qmr3LIItBzHFyP+qu8+/IA7x+//xOFFm/GpJg8FWd8uHiuWOVNHjxLKzN/o+oKRPs1rBamCjB4CDI9BhKDDi6ZmA2uvSJV2pdEeKL63mgPBb0o8QrFrUWSqoDEGqa8d6vlgXrQSzojIK3rxjd71xfoPcdrcBwHqJCw==</o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                    <Reference URI="#_1">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>zFBRC19YqaNfiONdpUCbcr4DQxs=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#_2">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>IkDHDcU8EXvtVZTidHKQd1q1g3s=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>a377DsYAjfklKE14NT1NjGWKNQaW2CCBXRpb08tzNcJKHPF07226AxqoA589y+IscFxwzlsQ+S5g4a5DkcXG25HYyNnXktHlQWzn9B1mvElQwY1pgq02hJ5g+Z3/ctyruqu4m1gKexYAtKthor06Zf800L4QNQlfYLDVawawwnc=</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-bf6b0577-5466-4726-ac5e-2ba07665475f-2" />
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" u:Id="_1">
        <sEncrypt_Input xmlns="http://vendor/xsdfile.xsd">
            <MaxUnmaskedDigits>4</MaxUnmaskedDigits>
            <isUnmaskedFromLeft>false</isUnmaskedFromLeft>
            <strRawValue>1234123412341234</strRawValue>
        </sEncrypt_Input>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: This post is a bit old, but did you ever find a solution. I am having the exact same issue with my WCF client and the `mustunderstand` flag causing issues?

Answer (score 2):

The last soap that you published looks like the one WSE generated. how does the wcf one looks like?
I suggest to use wcf with a custom binding with authenticatioMode of 'mutualCertificate' and not like the one you used. See [here](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/12-common-wcf-interop-confusions.html) more details on messages you may see.

Comment: I've added the WCF-generated SOAP request to the original question.  Thanks!

Comment: the wcf request signs just the timestamp element. the working request signs just the body and does not have a timestamp anyway. I suspect this is b/c you do not use mutualCertificate. try it, and optionally also set includeTimestamp to false. the link I gave can guide you in some of the cases that may happen here

Comment: I've tried a few of the fixes in your link, and I'm now receiving the error "SecurityVersion.WSSecurityJan2004 does not support header encryption. Header with name 'Security' and namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' is configured for encryption. Consider using SecurityVersion.WsSecurity11 and above or use transport security to encrypt the full message."

Comment: why do you need the lines in your code starting SecurityHeaderType? according the working soapui message there is no header encryption.

Comment: Those are the lines that prepare an input for the webservice and then call the webservice using that input as a parameter.  I was able to set the contract protection level to Sign, but now I am getting the error "The data in element 'o:Security' must be understood but cannot be handled" again.  Is there a way to turn off the MustUnderstand flag in WCF?

Comment: you would need to implement a custom message encoder to remove the mustUnderstood from the request yourself. But I don't think this is the issue. Please publish your current soap request.

Comment: Added the current request to the end of the original question.

Comment: the soapui messages signs the body. your message signs the timestamp. you should use mutualCertificate security.

Comment: I am: <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" includeTimestamp="false">

Comment: not sure if the latest updated soap you published is wcf or wse. in that soap something is strange - there is some h:Security header which I'm not sure what is doing there. Possibly related to SecurityHeaderType class. This does not appear in soapui and youi should not use it. As for the previous wcf sample it clearly has a timestamp so it cannot be the one matches the config in your last comment.